# How to pass props to the inputComponent material-ui?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

There is an example of Formatted inputs from material-ui docs https://stackblitz.com/edit/mfj4la

How to pass mask value `[/\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/]` to the TextMaskCustom component from parent component?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Custom props can be passed to the TextMaskCustom using inputProps

```
    <FormControl>
      <InputLabel>react-text-mask</InputLabel>
      <Input
        value={textmask}
        onChange={this.handleChange('textmask')}
        inputComponent={TextMaskCustom}
        inputProps={{
          mask:  [/\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/]
        }}
      />
    </FormControl>
```

Comment: how can I pass a function to it? My inputComponent is a datepicker and I have to get the selected date